# Compare each value of a row to corresponding value in a vector

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, comparison

I want to compare each value of a row of a data.frame to its corresponding value in a vector. Here is an example:

```
df1 <- matrix(c(2,2,4,8,6,9,9,6,4), ncol = 3)
df2 <- c(5,4,6)

> df1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    8    9
[2,]    2    6    6
[3,]    4    9    4

> df2
[1] 5 4 6
```

The comparison would be, if a value in a row of df1 is smaller than its corresponding value in df2, so row1: 2 < 5, 8 < 5, 9 < 5; row2: 2 < 4, 6 < 4, 6 < 4; row3: 4 < 6, 9 < 6, 4 < 6

```
> result
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Is there any way to do this without use of a loop?

Thanks lads!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just do a comparison to create the logical matrix

```
df1 < df2
#   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

The reason why it works is based on the recycling of the `vector`.  So, each elements of the vector 'df2', compares with the first columns 'df1', then goes to the second column and so on.

---

If the `length` of the vector is not equal to the number of columns of first dataset, we can replicate the vector

```
df1 < df2[row(df1)]
#    [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or another option is `sweep`

```
sweep(df1, 1, df2, "<")
```

Comment: But why do I receive this error message "Error in Ops.data.frame(short_term_g_OJ, as.vector(perpetual_g_OJ)) : 
  ‘<’ only defined for equally-sized data frames" when I compare a data.frame with 361 obs for 1221 var vs. a data.frame with 361 obs for one variable?

Comment: @Tobi1990 Based on the example showed, I assumed that the number of elements of vector i.e. 'df2' is equal to the number of rows.  I updated the post

Comment: thanks! Sorry is missed to mention that only number of rows is equal but number of columns does not necessarily match number of rows in the vector. df1 < df2[col(df1)] induced NAs for all columnnumbers > nrow(vector), but df1 < df2[row(df1)] works fine! cheers

Comment: @Tobi1990  You are right.  This is one of those examples where the changing to `row` rom `col` gives the same result.

Comment: Do you know how I could now replace each value of df1 by the corresponding value of df2, if the condition is true? Thanks

Comment: @Tobi1990  That is the reason I used `df1 < df2[col(df1)]`  Here, we assume that the number of columns of 'df1' is the same as the length of 'df2'.  It is basically replicating.  i.e. `df2[col(df1)]#
[1] 5 5 5 4 4 4 6 6 6;
 df2[row(df1)]
#[1] 5 4 6 5 4 6 5 4 6`.  If we check the output, in the 'col' case, each element is replicated thrice i.e. the number of rows of the first data, so that the lengths become equal and we compare the corresponding elements.  Similarly in the second case, the rows will be compared i.e.. 5 value compare the 1st row of df1, 4 with the 2nd row and 6 with 3rd